# VBA: Trying to copy and paste getting a compile error- expected: =

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

```
wsCopy.Range("B4").Copy
    wsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1,0)
```

Copying from one worksheet and pasting to another in a different workbook

Comment: These shouldn't be separate lines. Either combine them to one line, or use the line separation ` _`.

Comment: Try this  `wsCopy.Range("B4").Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1, 0)` in single line
`

Answer (score 0):

```
wsCopy.Range("B4").Copy wsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
```

Simple fix

Comment: `Copy` is a single line call. Your problem was that you were putting the `Destination` parameter on a different line.